# PDO query inside a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a `.php` file called `functions.php` where i must insert functions, for example I have a function called `db_connect` that connects to my database.

```
function db_connect()
{
    $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    return $PDO;
}

function Test($db)
{
    $result = false;
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM impressoras");
    $query->execute();
    #Iterate
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The page that is called:

```
<?php

   require('functions.php');
   $con = db_connect();
   print_r(Test($con));
?>
```

But this doesn't work, could someone help me? This appears to be error 500.

Comment: You need to invoke the function otherwise the function definition will just sit there.

Comment: i have posted my page that call , but return error 500.

Comment: With a 500 error, you should find a message inside your server error logs. That would help narrow the issue down. But I suspect what might be happening is the call to `Test` inside the definition of your `Test` function - you've got an infinite recursive loop there.

Comment: how could i fix this ?

Comment: Remove `Test();` from being called inside the function `Test()`, it's on line 7 of the method after `$get_name->execute();` and before the closing bracket, but having it there it calls itself over and over again.

Comment: do u know some tutorial to put a query inside a function or class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to stay away from GLOBALS, do injection of the database instead.

```
function db_connect()
    {
        $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME .   ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $PDO;
    }

function Test($db)
    {
        $result = false;
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM impressoras");
        $query->execute();
        # Iterate
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Here is how my strange example would run:

```
# Create connection
$con = db_connect();
# Inject
print_r(Test($con));
```

You would probably want to do other stuff in the `Test()` function but the idea is you want to inject the database connection, that way you can inject **the same** connection into any function on the page.

Comment: undestood , its because i have some querys , but i wanna put on functions , do u have some trick in how to make this ?

Comment: What do you mean you want to put on functions?

Comment: For example, I have a query that does a select of printers in my mysql table, but for not having to type the query all the time, when I wanted to select this query for printers I would call the function.

Comment: Ok, so you pass the database into that function and do a query inside and return the rows. I will revised the `Test()` to show that.

Comment: i have edit my post , dont work , am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: unhappy , still.

Comment: You must have more script that you aren't posting? There is no reason for error 500 at this point.

Comment: do a `try` and `catch` on the connection, there is probably an error being thrown by your database